# Question about Eigen::MatrixXd column-wise calculation

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there anyway to apply the column-wise calculation as follows?
(each column divided by the last entry of the column)

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(3,5), B(3,5); 

A << 1, 4, 9, 16, 25,
     2, 4, 6, 8, 10,
     1, 2, 3, 4, 5;

B = (A.col) / (A.bottomerows<1>).col;
```

and B would be:

```
B = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are `.hnormalized()` and `.homogeneous()`. Both can be applied `.colwise()` like this:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd B = A.colwise().hnormalized().colwise().homogeneous();
```

You can achieve the same with some `.replicate()` magic like this:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd B = A.array() / A.row(2).replicate(A.rows(),1).array();
```

(if `A` was an `ArrayXXd`, instead of a `MatrixXd`, you don't need to write the `.array()`)